# Car modeling technique

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I have been using blender for a few years now and I decided to model a detailed car to improve my skills in modeling, texturing, shading, lighting etc. However, for some reason, it seems like very daunting task for me. There are so many ways to get it wrong, that I don't know where to start.

My question is: What is/are a good - proven method/s to model a detailed (smooth) base shape of the car ([something like this](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/10440738_840058679415591_3113733821097643462_n.jpg?oh=aa6b006fbc61204e75abf8d126736762&oe=56C3A38A)) for further detailing?

The one that I want to model is [Dodge Challenger 1971](http://www.aggressivecars.com/modern-muscle-muscles-up-1971-dodge-challenger-rt/)

Thank you!

Comment: you might find this post interesting: [difference-between-hard-surface-and-organic-models](http://blog.digitaltutors.com/whats-the-difference-between-hard-surface-and-organic-models/)

Comment: Common workflow for this task is a quad oriented "vertex by vertex" modeling upon a blueprint base followed by Subdivision Surface modifier. You can see an example in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxGjhzV_Qkk

Comment: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Subdivision_Surface_Modeling

Comment: @Jerryno thanks for that link! Valuable resource